# junit testing with web driver

Tags: junit, webdriver

how to avoid test case to hanging in the middle. If i execute each its working fine. but all together if i run the test cases it is get stopped in the middle.
can any one help me regarding this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JUnit4, you can use the `Timeout` rule so if a test method takes "too long" it will fail, but allow the other tests to run. You have to be careful with doing this with WebDriver, because the `Timeout` rule is implemented with threads, and the `Driver` implementations are not thread-safe.

Also, avoid making calls that have very long timeouts. Instead, do short timeouts with a small number of retries.